# Is that possible to create bulk aws ALBs using powershell script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-elb

Is that possible to create bulk aws ALBs using powershell script?

If someone can provide Powershell script template, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, you can install AWS Tools for PowerShell. Check link below, there are examples there.

https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/

Comment: Do you have a script?

Comment: There are some examples in the link.

Answer (score -1):

```
`# Create HTTP Listener
$HTTPListener = New-Object -TypeName ‘Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancing.Model.Listener’
$HTTPListener.Protocol = ‘http’
$HTTPListener.InstancePort = 80
$HTTPListener.LoadBalancerPort = 80

#Create HTTPS Listener
$HTTPSListener = New-Object -TypeName ‘Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancing.Model.Listener’
$HTTPSListener.Protocol = ‘http’
$HTTPSListener.InstancePort = 443
$HTTPSListener.LoadBalancerPort = 80
$HTTPSListener.SSLCertificateId = ‘YourSSL’

# Create Load Balancer
New-ELBLoadBalancer -LoadBalancerName ‘YourLoadBalancerName’ -Listeners 
@($HTTPListener, $HTTPSListener) -SecurityGroups @($sgId) -Subnets @($sn1Id, $sn2Id) 
-Scheme ‘internet-facing’

 # Create Load Balancer
 New-ELBLoadBalancer -LoadBalancerName ‘YourLoadBalancerName’ -Listeners 
 @($HTTPListener, $HTTPSListener) -SecurityGroups @(‘SecurityGroupId’) -Subnets 
 @(‘subnetId1’, ‘subnetId2’) -Scheme ‘internet-facing’

 # Associate Instances with Load Balancer
 Register-ELBInstanceWithLoadBalancer -LoadBalancerName ‘YourLoadBalancerName’ - 
 Instances @(‘instance1ID’, ‘instance2ID’)

 # Create Application Cookie Stickiness Policy
 New-ELBAppCookieStickinessPolicy -LoadBalancerName ‘YourLoadBalancerName’ - 
 PolicyName ‘SessionName’ -CookieName ‘CookieName’

 # Set the Application Cookie Stickiness Policy to Load Balancer
 Set-ELBLoadBalancerPolicyOfListener -LoadBalancerName ‘YourLoadBalancerName’ - 
 LoadBalancerPort 80 -PolicyNames ‘SessionName’`
```

This script is just for one elb...how to transform this scripts to create bulk elbs? 
Also, where to mention AWS account credentials?